# jQuery Plugins - Call plugin method on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, numbers

I'm trying to develop a very basic jquery plugin that formats a number as a locale string using the toLocaleString method, so that I can just call my own method on numbers repeatedly in my scripts, but I can't seem to get it to work at all, and it always returns the number as undefined.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuwgtpt3/2/.

JS:

```
$.fn.formatCommas = function() {
  parseFloat(this).toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  })
}

var number = 1000000;

//attempt 1
var formatted = $.formatCommas(number);

//attempt 2
var formatted = $(number).formatCommas();

console.log('formatted number: ' + formatted);

$('#number').val(number);

$('#formatted').val(formatted);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, I already tested:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvviana/42jcdzz4/

```
$.fn.formatCommas = function(str){
        return parseFloat(str).toLocaleString(undefined, {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
}

var number = 1000000;

//attempt 1
var formatted = $.fn.formatCommas(number);


console.log('formatted number: ' + formatted);

$('#number').val(number);

$('#formatted').val(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `$.fn.formatCommas` you create a prototype method of jQuery object. Then it would need to be used like this

```
$('div').formatCommas() // or other selector, etc.
```

This is clearly not what you need for your purpose since .

What you are trying to do is creating simple static method:

```
$.formatCommas = function(str) {
  parseFloat(str).toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  })
}
```

However, honestly the functionality you are implementing would better be part of project utility module/functions, this should not be part of your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Here a prototype of code you can use in your case (I don't test but must work) :

```
//  ATTEMPT 1
(function ($){
    $.formatCommas = function(str){
        return parseFloat(str).toLocaleString(undefined, {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    });
}(jQuery));

//  ATTEMPT 2
// To avoid some problem if many library are declared
(function ($){
    // method augmentation
    $.fn.formatCommas = function() {
        var str = this.val();
        str = parseFloat(str).toLocaleString(undefined, {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
        this.val(str);

        // to permit continue method call after this one !
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

// ATTEMPT MERGE
(function ($){
    $.formatCommas = function(str){
        return parseFloat(str).toLocaleString(undefined, {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2
        });
    });

    $.fn.formatCommas = function() {
        var str = this.val();
        str  = $.formatCommas(str);
        this.val(str);

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```